# Can you describe a REST/HATEOAS API with WSDL?

Tags: rest, wsdl, hateoas

The [WSDL 2.0 Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-wsdl20-primer-20070626) has two examples (sections 5.3.3 and 5.3.4) mentioning REST, but a core constraint of REST is HATEOAS and those examples have no hypermedia controls.

Is it possible to describe hypermedia controls with WSDL (like one would with [Hydra](http://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/core/), for example)?

Comment: HATEOAS is an important characteristic of REST. Remove that and you usually end up with what people tend to call REST but it's not, i.e. a JSON Web API not much different than doing RPC over HTTP by using JSON instead of SOAP XML. Additionally, the jury is still out on [WADL](https://www.infoq.com/news/2007/06/rest-description-language/) for example. So the answer to your question would be "it depends", as in "it depends what you think REST is".